# Apache CXF not calling write() method on a StreamingOutput class

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, cxf

Below is the code I'm using to try to stream back a PDF.  I have done this exact thing before in another environment, but for some reason the write() method on StreamingOutput is not getting called.

No error is getting logged, and it's getting to the point where it's displaying "CONT" in the log, so I know it's getting to the constructor for the StreamingPdfOutput class at least.

What happens is that it eventually just returns a 404 to the client, even though all of this code is getting executed (except for the write() method).

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/fetchReportPdf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public StreamingOutput fetchReportPdf(@RequestBody MyRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
{
    LOG.info("start fetchReportPdf");
    // AssessmentResponse response = new AssessmentResponse();

    try
    {

        LOG.info("start pdf gen 3");
        File f = pdfUtil.generatePdf();

        response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + f.length());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.pdf\"");

        LOG.info("start response ok NEW: " + f);
        return new StreamingPdfOutput(f);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("ERR", ex);
    }

    LOG.info("start err build");
    return null; 
}

private class StreamingPdfOutput implements StreamingOutput
{
    File pdfFile;

    public StreamingPdfOutput(File f)
    {
        LOG.info("CONT");
        pdfFile = f;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        try
        {
            LOG.info("COPY: " + pdfFile);
            FileUtils.copyFile(pdfFile, os);
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(pdfFile);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            LOG.error("ERR COPY", t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try breakpointing in BinaryDataProvider.java's isWriteable. I found in my case the Java8 Lambda I was using was failing the isWritable test.